# Writing SQL query refering same table twice

Tags: python, sqlite, database-design, orm, sqlalchemy

Consider the following table definitions

```
class MCastSession(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'mcast_session'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  ip = Column(Integer)
  port = Column(Integer)
  __table_args__ = ( UniqueConstraint('ip', 'port'), )

class Topic(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'topic'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String, unique=True)
  mcast_session_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('mcast_session.id'))
  mcast_session = relationship('MCastSession')

class Host(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'host'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String, unique=True)

class Subscriber(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'subscriber'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  topic_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('topic.id'))
  topic = relationship('Topic')
  host_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('host.id'))
  host = relationship('Host')
  __table_args__ = ( UniqueConstraint('topic_id', 'host_id'), )

Example data:
Topic Session
T1    IP1:port1
T2    IP1:port2
T3    IP1:port2
T4    IP2:port1

Topic Host
T1    H1
T2    H1
T4    H2
```

I want to write a query to get all hosts which subscribe to multicast ip but doesn't handle all topics of the ip. In the above example. H1 has T1 and thus subscribes to IP1 but doesn't have T3 which also has the same IP1. So the query should return H1. H2 handles all the topics(T4) for the ips it subscribe(T4), so H2 should not be in the result. How to write the query for the above?

Comment: If someone is can help with just raw SQL query, that would also help

Comment: To reference same table twice: `select a.* from my_tab as first_reference join my_tab as second_reference on first_reference.ID = second_reference.ID +1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to look at the desired results is to apply following logic:

1. For each `IP` address calculate total number of `Topics` broadcasting
2. For each `Host` calculate total number of `Topics` broadcasting grouped by `IP` address
3. Desires Hosts are those for which the number of `Topics` per `IP` address is not equal (less actually) than the total for the `IP` address.

Following SA code should give you the desired `Host` instances:

```
# subquery to get number of topics per IP
subq_ip_topics = (session.query(
        MCastSession.ip.label("mcast_session_ip"),
        func.count(Topic.id).label("num_topics")
    )
    .join(Topic)
    .group_by(MCastSession.ip)
    ).subquery().alias("ip_topics")

# subquery to get number of topics per host per ip
subq_host_ip_topics = (session.query(
        Host.id.label("host_id"),
        MCastSession.ip.label("mcast_session_ip"),
        func.count(Topic.id).label("num_topics")
    )
    .join(Subscriber)
    .join(Topic)
    .join(MCastSession)
    .group_by(Host.id, MCastSession.ip)
    ).subquery().alias("host_ip_topics")

# final query: get those Hosts where results on both sub-queries do not match
query = (session.query(Host)
        .join(subq_host_ip_topics, Host.id == subq_host_ip_topics.c.host_id)
        .join(subq_ip_topics, and_(
            subq_host_ip_topics.c.mcast_session_ip == subq_ip_topics.c.mcast_session_ip,
            subq_host_ip_topics.c.num_topics != subq_ip_topics.c.num_topics
            ))
        )
```

which produces the `SQL` code below (for `SQLite`):

```
SELECT  host.id AS host_id, host.name AS host_name

FROM    host

JOIN   (SELECT  host.id AS host_id,
                mcast_session.ip AS mcast_session_ip,
                count(topic.id) AS num_topics
        FROM    host
        JOIN    subscriber
            ON  host.id = subscriber.host_id
        JOIN    topic
            ON  topic.id = subscriber.topic_id
        JOIN    mcast_session
            ON  mcast_session.id = topic.mcast_session_id
        GROUP BY host.id, mcast_session.ip
       ) AS host_ip_topics
    ON  host.id = host_ip_topics.host_id

JOIN   (SELECT  mcast_session.ip AS mcast_session_ip,
                count(topic.id) AS num_topics
        FROM    mcast_session
        JOIN    topic
            ON  mcast_session.id = topic.mcast_session_id
        GROUP BY mcast_session.ip
       ) AS ip_topics
    ON  host_ip_topics.mcast_session_ip = ip_topics.mcast_session_ip
    AND host_ip_topics.num_topics != ip_topics.num_topics
```

---

Now, if you want to use the same table multiple times in the query, you can use [`aliased`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.aliased) for that. The code below will return a list of tuples `(MCaseSession, NNN)`, where `NNN` is the number of MCastSession objects with the same `IP`:

```
aliased_MCastSession = aliased(MCastSession, name="MCastSession2")
qry = session.query(\
    MCastSession, \
    func.count(aliased_MCastSession.id).label("number_with_same_ip")).\
filter(MCastSession.ip == aliased_MCastSession.ip).\
group_by(MCastSession)
```

But I did not need to do this for the solution proposed because I used subqueries for that.

Answer (score 1):

Query bellow will result the target:

```
select distinct host1.name host_name
  from Subscriber Subscriber1
 inner join host host1
    on host1.id = Subscriber1.Host_Id
 inner join topic topic1
    on topic1.id = Subscriber1.Topic_Id
 inner join mcast_session mcast_session1
    on mcast_session1.id = topic1.mcast_session_id
 where (select count(*)
          from mcast_session
         where mcast_session.ip = mcast_session1.ip) !=
       (select count(*)
          from topic
         inner join mcast_session
            on topic.mcast_session_id = mcast_session.id
         where mcast_session.ip = mcast_session1.ip)
```

For explanation of the logic, the query may helps:

```
select  host1.name host_name,
       topic1.name topic_name,
       mcast_session1.ip,
       mcast_session1.port,
(select count(*)
          from mcast_session
         where mcast_session.ip = mcast_session1.ip) host_to_topic_registeration,
       (select count(*)
          from topic
         inner join mcast_session
            on topic.mcast_session_id = mcast_session.id
         where mcast_session.ip = mcast_session1.ip
           ) ip_topic_count
  from Subscriber Subscriber1
 inner join host host1
    on host1.id = Subscriber1.Host_Id
 inner join topic topic1
    on topic1.id = Subscriber1.Topic_Id
 inner join mcast_session mcast_session1
    on mcast_session1.id = topic1.mcast_session_id
```

***[sqlfiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f4dd/2)***: